# How to create a button that makes a new text field appear on screen?

Tags: actionscript-3

I've been having trouble getting this button to work. I want it so that whenever you click it, a new text field pops up that you can type stuff in. This is supposed to be for a trivia-like game, where the user inputs their own questions and answers. Here's the code so far...

This is the text field's properties -

```
    QuestionTextField = new TextField();
            QuestionTextField.defaultTextFormat = SmallTextFormat;
            QuestionTextField.textColor = 0x660000;
            QuestionTextField.x = stage.stageWidth * 0.1;
            QuestionTextField.y = 200;
            QuestionTextField.width = stage.stageWidth * 0.8;
            QuestionTextField.height = 20;
            QuestionTextField.selectable = false;
            QuestionTextField.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
            QuestionTextField.border = true;
            QuestionTextField.multiline = true;
            QuestionTextField.wordWrap = true;
```

And this is the function that is supposed to create a new text field every time the button is clicked-

```
     private function AddQuestionButtonClicked(m:MouseEvent){
        for(var i = Questions.length; i>=1; i--){
            container_buttonsMC.addChild(QuestionTextField);
            Questions.push(QuestionTextField);
            QuestionTextField.y += 20
        }
     }
```

Notes : "Questions" is an array that holds the number of text fields there are, container_buttonsMC holds all of the buttons on that are on the game's main menu.

The problem is that whenever I click it, it 1. Doesn't actually create a new text field, but instead moves it a certain amount of pixels down, and 2. It sort of duplicates the text field's position...if that makes ANY sense at all. If I click on the button once, it will move the text field down by 20 pixels. If I click on it again, it will move it down by 40 pixels, then by 80, and so on...

I also traced the length of the array, and surprisingly enough, the number that appeared would double every time I clicked it. However, only one text field is visible (apparently). It probably has something to do with the for loop's action, but I don't know for sure. Does anyone have an idea as to what the problem is? (Thanks in advance, I'm still new to AS3 and programming in general)

Answer (score 0):

First, each need to create a new textfield every time you click the button, rather than adding it to the stage. With what you have at the moment, you only created one text field.

Secondly, you only want to do add one more text field, right? So instead of using a loop, which will create multiple new text fields, just create one extra text field and add it to the list.

The code will look something like

```
private function AddQuestionButtonClicked(m:MouseEvent){
    var QuestionTextField:TextField = new TextField()
    QuestionTextField.defaultTextFormat = SmallTextFormat;
    QuestionTextField.textColor = 0x660000;
    QuestionTextField.x = stage.stageWidth * 0.1;
    QuestionTextField.y = 200;
    QuestionTextField.width = stage.stageWidth * 0.8;
    QuestionTextField.height = 20;
    QuestionTextField.selectable = false;
    QuestionTextField.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
    QuestionTextField.border = true;
    QuestionTextField.multiline = true;
    QuestionTextField.wordWrap = true;

    // You can adjust the 50 here to control the spacing between text fields
    QuestionTextField.y += 50 * Questions.length
    container_buttonsMC.addChild(QuestionTextField);
    Questions.push(QuestionTextField);
}
```

Comment: This fixed the array problem, but the preexisting text field disappears whenever I click the button. Its removing the text field, changing its y value , and adding it again.

Comment: Hm. Are you sure the line with `new TextField()` is in there? Is there anything that would remove a text field?

Comment: Can you add this to the end and tell me what happens?
`if (Questions.length > 1) {
   trace(Questions[0] === Questions[1]); }`

Comment: I think I figured out something... The text field isnt being deleted, it just appears that there's one because they are stacked on top of each other...

Comment: Also, that thing that you told me to add gave me the 1009 error.

Comment: Ah, I meant for you to add that to the end of the function, but not after the function. The point of that was the check whether each text text field was the same or not.

The line `QuestionTextField.y += 50 * Questions.length` should make sure each new text field is set to a different position, and should only move the new text field, without changing any of the existing ones. Is that working?

Comment: It's not working, unfortunately... I know this is a really old question, but I'm trying to get it to work again. The y value of the text fields exponentially increases.